# Why angular2 ngIf doesnt work in HTML file?

Tags: html, angular

I work on my project and I set a flag from .ts file but it is not hide the `<div>` tag despite of correct value.

The HTML file:

```
<div *ngIf="this.isPickupOrderAvaliable">
    <button 
    class="btn btn-primary pickup-order-button"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#pickupOrderModal">! PickupOrderButton !</button>
</div>

{{this.isPickupOrderAvaliable}}
```

the .ts file, its called after

```
submitPickupOrder() {
  if (this.pickupOrderForm.invalid) {
    console.log('this.form is invalid');
  }

this.http.post(`${appConfig.HostUrl}dashboardservice/PickupOrder/`, 
  this.pickupOrderForm.getRawValue()).subscribe((x: any) => {
    this.isPickupOrderAvaliable = x._body;
    console.log(`this.isPickupOrderAvaliable: ${this.isPickupOrderAvaliable}`);
});
}
```

On the image below, the false show the value of `this.isPickupOrderAvaliable`, but the button still visible.

[image]

Have you any idea about where i made mistake in this code?

Comment: Please show the output of  `console.log(`this.isPickupOrderAvaliable: ${this.isPickupOrderAvaliable}`);`

Comment: take account if your'e receiving a string or a boolean ("false" is true -sorry the joke-). If is a **string** you need use *ngIf="this.isPickupOrderAvaliable=='true'" or, better, in subscribe you use `this.isPickupOrderAvaliable = x._body=="true"?true:false`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to print the value of  `x._body` and check if its true or false. If its true, the button would be displayed and if its false button would be hided. Set the default value to false in ts file